# Integrate CKEditor as inline editor with Angular 4

Tags: angular, ckeditor

Help me how to integrate CKEditor as inline editor with angular2/4/6.
in below link it explains only direct integration.https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

Comment: What integration do you need? What do you mean by `direct integration`?

Comment: Generally editor toolbar will be displayed on page load for each html element, i do not want like that. When i click on the any html element then the editor box should be displayed.

Comment: And please, clarify if the question is about CKEditor 4 or CKEditor 5. Those are two different editors.

Answer (score 0):

**ANGULAR 4 INTRGRATION**

1- Install "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.9" using npm.

2- Add "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.1/full/ckeditor.js" with script tag in the in index.html

3- Import CKEditorModule in the module  of the page you want ckeditor for.

4- Set configuration as you like

```
   ckEditorWithImageConfig = {
        "toolbarGroups": [
            {"name": "basicstyles", "groups": ["basicstyles"]},
            {"name": "links", "groups": ["links"]},
            {"name": "styles", "groups": ["heading"]},
            {"name": "paragraph", "groups": ["list", "blocks", "indent"]},
            {"name": "document", "groups": ["mode", "undo"]},
            {"name": "insert", "groups": [ "Image" ] }
        ],
        "removeButtons": "Save,Templates,Find,Replace,Scayt,SelectAll,Subscript,Superscript,CreateDiv,NewPage,Print,Preview," +
        "Anchor,Font,FontSize,Styles,Flash,Table,HorizontalRule,Smiley,SpecialChar,PageBreak,Iframe",
        "removePlugins": "elementspath",
        "removeDialogTabs": "image:advanced",
        "extraPlugins": "uploadimage",
        "filebrowserImageUploadUrl": "url"
    };
```

5- Add this in html and pass config to [config]

```
<ckeditor name='intro'                                                                   
  [config]= ckEditorWithImageConfig formControlName="text">
</ckeditor>
```

6- Now enjoy...

Comment: This is same has general editor integration, i want example for inline editor. i.e. when i click on any html element in the page then editor popup should display.